If the rover found a men's wristwatch on the sands of Mars, can we infer Intelligent design?
This question is usually asked about finding a watch on the beach and inferring that it was created, not something the crustaceans just happened to stick together to hide under.
The valid objection to this argument (thank you @Syed) is: we already know that humans exist, they make watches, and they take them off at the beach to go swimming.
But if the rover found an watch on Mars that has a 25 hour dial and strange symbols, no one would think for a moment that it wasn't designed, even though there is no other evidence of a designer, no motivation for him to put one there, and no other extraterrestrial watches.
It would be taken as de facto proof that something more complex than the watch existed on Mars at one time.
Why isn't the existence of life on earth just like the watch?

THREE OBJECTIONS
DAWKINS' OBJECTION
"God did it" implies a creator, who must then be explained. But not only is there no evidence for this creature, the probability of God spontaneously appearing out of nowhere is FAR less than ordinary life just appearing.
Dawkins — who has been like a god to me after he wrote The Selfish Gene — is correct on both points. But the complexity of the creator is a non sequitur. It begs the question. To infer the existence of the watchmaker, we don't have to:

Know anything at all about this creature
Know whether or not there are watches on other planets
Believe he left the watch for us to find
Ask why the watch wasn't a grandfather clock
Worship this space alien
Guess why he lost his watch
Infer his motivation, other than that he likes handsome timepieces. Curiously, we CAN infer that. I'm willing to believe that an angel didn't just bump into the control panel.


In particular, we don't have to guess the likelihood that an extraterrestrial watch factory exists because we found one of the extraterrestrial watches. The probability of a watchmaker then becomes 100 percent, modulo even worse explanations, like a time-traveling Federation worker losing his watch at Utopia Planitia.
Ancient weathermen didn't have to know that water condenses out of cold air, to observe that it always rains in the evening of a humid day.
NEIL DEGRASSE TYSON'S OBJECTION:
When faced with something we don't understand, the first thing stupid people conclude is that it must have happened by Harry Potter Magic — God did it.
This is certainly true. We didn't understand lightning? God's mad at us! It didn't rain and our crops failed? God hates us! We won the war? God loves the high priest!
Tyson correctly points out that one by one, as we've peeled back these mysteries, god has receded further back into our ignorance — the only place he can hide.
I must say, his argument has effectively made me feel ashamed of believing in intelligent design.
But as a scientist, I must believe what I see evidence of, whether I like it or not.
...And I don't like it! I would prefer a natural explanation, but there doesn't appear to be one — even if Neil Degrasse Tyson makes fun of me.
Sagan himself pointed out that 2,000 years ago, it was legitimate to think that maybe rain is intentional on the part of someone or something. BUT (and I'm paraphrasing from my ancient memory):

We did experiments that showed praying doesn't make a damn bit of difference to rainfall or anything else.  This should have pushed them toward another explanation whether they had one or not.

We finally learned how weather really works.

This crude but reasonable model only turned into religious dogma when the believers refused to accept the vastly simpler true understanding.


The complexity of life isn't magic, it's technology sufficiently advanced to be indistinguishable from magic.
Clarke's complete quote in Profiles of the Future was, "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic. Anything evolved beyond that is indistinguishable from God."
THE TIME OBJECTION:
Millions of acceptably improbable things happened over a very long time, and they added up.
But that doesn't solve anything either. Natural selection doesn't create complexity, it only selects from choices that already existed for some reason.
Even if you assume that every million years, a shard of natural metal just happens to be weathered into the size and shape of a little gear, there is still no reason to believe that natural selection would cause these gears to assemble themselves into a watch -- relentlessly and purposefully.
In the case of evolution, we can look at the fossil record and see that indeed, all the little gears really DID self-assemble into complex structures.
We have piles of Homo Erectus bones and piles of Habilis bones, but none in between. And with every one of these version releases, the same unlikely mutations happen again. And again, and again.
That's not evidence that it happened by chance and fortune; it's evidence that we live in a watch factory.


Discussion has been moved here. Please do only post if you want to improve the question.

I take a skeptics approach to formal theories. If it isn't useful for making predictions, or have some other utility - I stay agnostic. I would take that God did it, as a tentative possibility, amidsts a host of possibilities. But, I don't see any benefit to putting it forward as a hypothesis, if I can't test it, it doesnt predict anything. If Intelligent Design was used in an indespensible way, to predict/understand/model a novel phenomenon, that is otherwise indescribable. Then, I would take the Intellignet Design as a serious hypothesis. ( rather than a tentative possibility)

I'm not saying we can't assume god did it, if we found such a Galaxy. But, I don't see any good reason to do so. I don't find "because it appears to be what happened" to be a good reason. For me, hypothesis are tools I use to understand, test, probe the world. I don't see how Intelligent Design can be used to do that. However, it's entirely possible someone smarter than me does exactly that.

The most obvious objection that you didn't include in your list is that the analogy doesn't hold, because watches and living beings are fundamentally different.
If I found a watch on mars, yes I'd suppose it was brought by someone, either human or something else if human intervention is eliminated. And I wouldn't be irrational, just like people of ancient times who knew so few about biology and chemistry when they came to the same conclusion about life.
But then if I found a mechanism by which watches could reproduce and create other watches, along with an understanding of those mechanisms. If I found and studied a process by which watches assimilate nutrients from their environment, refined them and use them to build themselves, again using natural processes I can reproduce in the lab. If, at last, I found a fossil record of watches across millions of years, with a clear correlation showing that the further back in time the simpler the watches, down to simple elements I can still find around in nature, like rudimentary springs and coils, and who tend to stick together, without external intervention, in some way that favours the apparition of a time measuring mechanism. If I found all this evidence that watches came to be according to natural processes, it would be foolish to stick to the intelligent design hypothesis.
People who are impressed by the watch maker argument act like neanderthals dumbfounded by the diversity of nature. They forget that, unlike cave people, we have much more knowledge about the workings of life. Neanderthals were not thinking irrationally considering the elements of data they had access to, they didn't knew better. We are in a different situation and therefore our rational conclusion ought to be different.

Agreed but even before, I would argue that there was never a need to postulate a designer, since postulating one always begs the question of what created it. This doesn’t apply to humans because we already know they exist, but for anything else we don’t, it will be nothing but a speculation, ether now or hundreds of years ago.

"act like neanderthals" That's racism. Or specieism.

@tkruse funny. Unless you are contesting that neanderthals knew less than we do about biochemistry, which has nothing to do with race or species.

Then why pick on a different race and species, if you could just as well point to early homo sapiens, who knew likely as little about biochemistry as homo neanderthalensis?

@tkruse:  Valid point. How about saying bronze age humans instead, since that's about the earliest time period for which we have any records of what people believed.  The issue isn't stupidity (though there's no evidence that the Neanderthals were especially stupid) but ignorance. We have learned a lot more over the millennia, and can do better than waving our hands without evidence.

As a side note, remember that modern homo sapiens is part neanderthal. Given that our definition of species is based on cross fertility, perhaps the Neanderthals should be considered a breed rather than a separate species.

@tkruse so if I say "I bet I know more than Ann Boleyn about the theory of relativity" I'm being sexist? I'm just trying to understand the logic here...

@keshlam which would mean my remark isn't specist since we are the same species. I mean... I love hair splitting as much as any other philosophy enthusiast, but there's overdoing it.

@armand: It's a silly digression anyway. That's philosophers for you, try to make a joke and some will be tempted to try to respond to it as if it was serious, presuming that everyone will understand that they are just extending the joke. Some engineers are notorious for doing the same thing.  I learned long ago that my sardonic sense of humor does not translate well on the internet, and try to either suppress it or make it blatant, but I don't always succeed.

@armand, if you said you know "more than a woman...", I feel that might be sexist. If you talk about Ann Boleyn, I don't know. Without more context it's unclear what your sentence could be implying.

@tkruse exactly. But you have the whole context of my mentioning neanderthals, so we both know you are splitting hair.

Yes, thick neanderthal hair.

A watch or sundial on Mars wouldn't be all that different from a watch or sundial on Earth. These aren't identified by complexity, they're identified by properties of design, which specifically differentiates it from naturally-forming. One might consider (off the top of my head) materials used, how they are connected, sharp and uniform edges, lines and corners, the presence of various geometric shapes that we don't see in nature, etc.
Most of these properties would increase the likelihood of design, whereas it being on Mars would greatly decrease the likelihood of design, on account of there seemingly not being any intelligent living organisms around. Whether we end up concluding design would depend on the specifics.
So that's why this doesn't work for life, because the criteria we use for this was never complexity to begin with, and life doesn't show these properties of design. And if they did, they'd probably be bad properties, because life seems to form, grow, reproduce and spread naturally. The whole point of coming up with properties of design is to differentiate it from naturally-forming things. If you're trying to say naturally-forming things are themselves designed using those properties (through an invisible being that act through nature or acts in undetectable ways), that brings those properties into doubt, because they would no longer differentiate design from naturally-forming things.
Three objections
"Three objections" - did any of these people actually respond to specific issue at hand, i.e. is this actually "Dawkins' objection" to this question, or are you taking some quotes they said about other things, or your own interpretation of what they might say. It's misleading to present something as "...'s objection" if they weren't actually responding to the question at hand.
Dawkins' objection
"the complexity of the creator is a non sequitur" - if you're using complexity as your criteria for concluding design, and your proposed creator doesn't have a creator, then their complexity is absolutely relevant. If they are complex (more complex, even), then this would just be kicking the can down the road. You'd be adding a pointless claim as a solution to a problem that it's not actually a solution to. Note that this doesn't apply when properties of design that aren't complexity, like those mentioned above (but you may still have a differentiating problem, like mentioned above).
"because we found one of the extraterrestrial watches" - that's just begging the question: assuming that the "watch" is designed to sidestep discussion of the possibility that it isn't.
As for the motivations of a creator, that it also relevant in determining how likely any given creator is (maybe not that relevant then if you just leave it at "there is a creator", without saying anything about their personality or what they might want from us). Like if you find a sundial in Africa, it would be reasonable to say it had a human creator, who probably wanted to tell the time. It would not be reasonable to say it had a time-travelling-wizard-alien creator who just felt like messing with humans. Although it seems like we're still a long way from "there is a creator".
Tyson's objection
"as a scientist, I must believe what I see evidence of" - it very much seems like you missed Tyson's point. This isn't actually any sort of counter-argument to what he said. It's merely an assertion that such evidence exists (despite the majority of actual professional scientists in relevant fields not seeing it - I won't speculate on what qualifications or experience you have to qualify yourself as a "scientist").
"it was legitimate to think that maybe rain is intentional on the part of someone or something" - the literal exact point is that it's not reasonable, though. People throughout history kept saying "God did it" to things they didn't understand, and they were proven wrong time and time again. It literally shows how unreliable it is to say "God did it" to things one doesn't understand, how that's an unreasonable thing to say, if you care about what's true (and if you don't care about what's true, you might be in the wrong place). The conclusion to draw from that should not be "yeah, all those people might've been wrong, but me, I think I'm right, though". That's just repeating the mistakes of the past.
Time objection
"In the case of evolution, we can look at the fossil record and see that indeed, all the little gears really DID self-assemble into complex structures" - "self-assemble" loosely suggests some intelligence or self-guidance, which there wasn't. There were just vast amounts of random mutations. Countless organisms ended up with the "bad" mutations, and died out. The ones with beneficial mutations were more successful at passing on their genes, and that, very slowly, led to increased complexity, as more complex physiology and behaviour allowed organisms to successfully deal with a wide range of environmental hazards and difficulties.
"We have piles of Homo Erectus bones and piles of Habilis bones, but none in between" - I really wish people would stop spitting in the face of people who've dedicated their lives to studying anthropology and biology more generally, and sowing distrust of science and distrust of experts, with such misleading claims (usually made with little to no relevant education or experience, and little knowledge of the relevant evidence). Human evolution shows slow incremental change, and that includes habilis, rudolfensis, gautengensis, erectus, naledi, florensiensis, ergaster, sapiens, etc., and that's just on the homo side, while there are also plenty of australopithecus species that came before. You just picked some point in the middle of that, and decided there must be a gap evolution didn't cross, without breaking down the evidence and considering the criteria for making that judgement, such as brain case size, tooth size, bipedalism, sexual dimorphism, ulnar opposition, and other changes. Also, erectus was around for millions of years and shows a significant amount of variety - it's debated whether these should considered different species. Reminder: species are a man-made construct to classify a group of animals at a particular period of time, when in reality there isn't a definitive point where one species gives birth to another species - it's a slow gradual change. We're constantly grouping animals into new species and refining what our classifications are.

I'd quibble on the recognizing design by its characteristics, and emphasize the big one: a watch doesn't reproduce (nor did its ancestors) so there is no known way for it to have evolved to this complexity without someone having made it. We have a pretty darn good model for evolution and selection for life, and in fact we deliberately use it in breeding livestock and crops. And we are still learning more about how epigenetics feed into the process. When we had no better ideas, miracles were a good placeholder. They aren't needed now.

A watch cannot be the product of evolution as we know it. It doesn't reproduce, hence it doesn't have even one chance to evolve.
Life does reproduce, does reproduce imperfectly, and has been around a bleeping long time -- long enough, in the view of many of us, to have reached its current state purely on that and natural selection.
If we find a watch on the beach, we know how it got there. If we find a watch on mars, we will need to figure out how it got there. Given that it is recognizably a human-made watch, my assumption today would be that it got dropped into one of the Mars probes and managed to get thrown clear during the landing. My assumption 100 years from now would be the same as finding a watch on an earthly beach: a passing human dropped it.
Watches need creators, life does not. You can speculate that it had one anyway, if you want to, but it is a needless additional complication.

ADDENDUM:
Regarding the discontinuities in the fossil record: think about any other historical record.
We don't have documentation for every day over the past thousands of years. We assume the world has continued to exist, rather than believing that every gap means a new creation. We can interpolate, and we can see how the world has developed over time by assuming that things which are sufficiently similar are probably part of the same history. And we accept that as we go back farther, the record becomes spottier.
We don't have documentation for every version of spoken or written language over that time. This is a case where there probably were multiple creations, if you go back far enough, but we still assume that similarity is enough to trace continuity back toward those origins. Modern English is not a separate creation from Old English; it evolved, we can see that it evolved, we accept that it evolved. And we accept that as we go back farther, fewer documents have survived.
We don't have all the intermediate versions of the Bible. Unless you are an extremely young Earth creationist, you don't assume that its history started with the most recent edition; you accept that it developed from earlier editions in other languages, with or without the Apocrypha, with or without changes in formatting, and so on. People celebrate when a new fragment is found to help fill in that history; they certainly don't expect to find complete books. I presume you wouldn't argue that each version of the Bible was created separately.
Consider the history of philosophy...
Exactly the same principle applies to paleontology. There will be gaps in the record. But that is not reason to assume separate creations; we assume continuity of time, and look for commonalities and changes across the samples we do have to help us understand what the intermediate forms might have been and what forces may have been driving change. Remember that science does not claim inerrancy; it tries to produce the best models of the world it can with the information and analysis that we currently have, and we refine those models  as new data becomes available. We can work with a discontinuous history, and we can accept that as we look back further, we will have fewer and fewer specimens to examine. And if a specimen shows up that does not fit our previous model, we try to authenticate it, and if it looks genuine we try to account for why something unexpected might have happened.
If you want to challenge history, you need a believable reason that a break might have occurred, when everything we have says that time, and development, has been continuous. That's true for biological history as well. Yes, you can say that the fossils were created as a lie, or that homo sapiens was a separate creation, but there really is no reason to believe those theories except past confusion and tradition; they don't fit the evidence as well as the evolutionary model does. Or you can argue that the historical record is, in fact, telling us the truth but that a creator had its thumb on the scales at various branching points; that is either the god of the gaps, or a god that has left no evidence and is accepted purely on faith. Either way, arguing that gaps in the record indicate new Creation de novo really doesn't fly. It isn't impossible, assuming you believe in a deity which could do that, but it is needlessly complicated, inserting an explanation where none is required. It certainly isn't an argument that is going to convince anyone who doesn't already accept an interventionist deity.
In this case, it's pretty clear that miracles were a placeholder for ignorance. As we have learned more, the need for them has simply fallen away.
Obligatory song reference: The Word Of God by Cat Faber
... So turn and look where best you think
The story is unfurled:
Humans wrote the bible. 
God wrote the world.



A watch cannot be the product of evolution as we know it == I didn't say evolved; it's an analogy. The point being that they were both appear purposefully designed. == > it doesn't reproduce, hence it doesn't have even one chance to evolve. == No, it's just an analogy. Every generation contains the entire history of all evolution. We started a single cell, then into a worm, a fish, a small mammal, and a human. Every cycle adds one more link to the chain. But in every cycle, the entire chain is reproduced. == Each generation is more highly developed than the last. [con'td]


Natural selection only selects between preexisting choices. These highly adaptive random changes look exactly like intentional. Just what goes on on inside the cell is case closed, at least for me. God is a potter, we are the art, and evolution is the spinning wheel.

@MissUnderstands: Mutation occurs continuously; we see it in our domestic animals and plants. Most mutations are fatal and immediately drop out of the record. Some are survivable and gain or lose presence in the population base pretty much randomly, possibly turning out to be helpful or harmful later on. A very, very few -- resistance to disease, longer breeding life, better ability to find food or avoid becoming food -- are immediately advantageous, and even these have to survive random challenges long enough to spread into the population base. Over eons, that really is enough.

And no, ontogeny does not recapitulate philogyny. We bear the marks of all our history, but we do not contain a complete record of the past, nor a prediction of the future.

If you want to disbelieve in genetics, there's no point in having the conversation.


ontogeny does not recapitulate philogyny.  === It most certainly does! An embryo goes through all the stages of its ancestors during development. That's EXACTLY what happens! Every cycle adds a new link in the chain, like adding a rattle at the end of a rattlesnake's tail with every cycle. Every subsequent version is further evolved, by definitiont. The DNA is  recombined sexually, creating a brand new species of one.


No, @MissUnderstands it doesn't. That was a guess that we jumped to early on, based on rough similarity of stages to other animals. As we have understood it better, and looked at which tissues are being developed rather than just what the appearance is, the recapitulation claim has been refuted. You might want to catch up on the science of the past couple decades.
